# Unexpected result of uv mapping with cube projection or Magic UV Box (Non continuous map)

Tags: uv

I imported object from AutoCAD and did UV mapping for it using cube projection, the texture has tiles, I simulated the problem using the color grid texture in below screenshots, it is expected that the mapping will be continuous along each side but it's not, it seems there are UV islands that make the texture stop at certain edges (there is no seams at all), I tried also the plugin Magic UV with same results, how can I make the texture continuous?

Note: I have many objects and most of them are complicated to do manual unwrap, so I prefer doing it with box UV mapping to save time.

Link to blender file:
https://we.tl/t-yGQRw3MKvI

Attached screenshots of the problem:

[[image: Texture is not continuous at some places][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4OsK.jpg)

[image: Texture is not continuous at some places]

Comment: you need to add [seams](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-blender-a/9780133886283/ch08lev2sec5.html) to your model. it's not possible to have it continuous on every edge. where do you want the seams to be located? select the edges you want to be as seam and do `Ctrl`+`E` and select `Mark Seam` and then Unwrap your model again by going into `Edit Mode` and selecting everything with `A` and then press `U` > *Cube Projection*

Comment: and you might want to scale up your model, it's really small at *0.129 x 0.0925 x 0.2* meters

Comment: Cube Projection will project on the 3 axis, so it's normal that the texture is discontinued

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I tried to add seams but when doing the cube projection the texture is uncontinuous in places that don't have a seam (the clouded areas in the screenshots), I know it cannot be continuous on every edge but it should be continuous on every plane (plane projection xz or yz for example should be continuous because it's a box projection, but not when we cross the planes), I think it's something to do with the structure of the object itself not the UV map, because the texture is cut at edges where there is no seam existing, I think these edges are same isolines in the AutoCAD file)

Comment: @moonboots yes normal between axis planes but not in same plane (xy for example)

Comment: these are not the same faces, you'll see it in Edit mode

Comment: the geometry is horrible it needs to be fixed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select all the side faces and, as they are tris, convert to quads with *Face > Tris to Quads*:

[image]

Then keep the faces selected, shift select one face and press <kbd>U</kbd> *(Unwrap) > Follow Active Quads*:

[image]

Now you'll have a continuous texture all around the side:

[image]

Comment: I tried the steps but I think I am missing something, in "follow active quads" did you choose "length"? I still have 2 directions for the texture, instead of A7,A8,A1,A2 in your image I have them rotated 90 degrees. Also, if this worked, it will solve the problem of same length side faces, but if sides have variant length it will not work, right?

Comment: Length is probably the good option, and I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, have you convert all the tris to quads? Also the result seems correct to me

Comment: yes I converted them to quads, what type of unwrap did you do? cube projection? I still have 2 directions, I tried many things but the middle parts are always in another direction, I attached an image here: https://we.tl/t-H7Uy5pieW9

Comment: How does cube projection work? isn't supposed that it will automatically map the whole side in one direction correctly?

Comment: Cube Projection will project the texture depending on the face normal, so the texture will be discontinued as soon as a face is considered as oriented towards Z instead of towards X for example. As for your UV that is cut in two parts, I'm not sure what's happening, could you please share your file?

Comment: This link contains the file after doing "tris to quads" and "follow active quads": https://we.tl/t-T0j9q5UiB4   , the original file before modifications is attached in the question itself.

Comment: In that case, is there a quick way to let blender consider all sides oriented towards x for example? because this will be applied to many objects

Comment: I've just tested the file you share, it works fine, you need to select all the face (make the view transparent with Alt Z) and then U > Follow Active Quads, and it will be unwrapped in one island only, not two. As for your question I'm not sure what you mean, in the Texture Coordinate there's a Normal output that you can plug into the (Converter) Separate XYZ for example, but please give more details about what you mean and in what way the solution I propose doesn't fit

Comment: I did it correctly with Alt Z, I don't know what was the problem, I think Alt Z helped to select all of them in one window without skipping any face, thank you very much for your help. My question was about if there is a fast way to apply cube projection for many objects (100 for example) because in case of complicated objects the "follow active quads" might be difficult to apply,

Comment: as I understood, the projection is considering the normal angles to know each face to which plane, as a result there are places the texture is uncontinuous (in place of change between plane to plane for like xy to yz especially in tile textures, is there any way to avoid the texture uncontinuity? for example by telling blender which faces are yz projection? or by controlling the place of tile cut to look continuous?

Comment: I don't see how you could avoid discontinuity with Cube Project. For more "organic" textures, like for example wood or stone (and not grids, bricks, etc) you can use the Object output of the Texture Coordinate, in the Image Texture choose Box instead of Flat and play with the Blend value, it will make a smooth transition between X and Z etc

Comment: Yes it is a great idea in case of non-tile textures, thank you very much